# dygraphs setVisibility() with muiltiple plots on page

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I've been working with dygraphs and have gotten a webpage working well with check boxes to toggle on and off visibility for a potentially infinite number of dygraphs on a page.

I am however now stuck when I've added buttons to set the values all on or all off.

I've found a basic example I've followed: http://dygraphs.com/tests/color-visibility.html which has the ID names of the check boxes 0-3. This works well with one plot, or even with multiple plots as long as I don't have to call the ID of the check boxes. I had the whole system working with repeating the ID numbers.

However when I add a button to automatically check the box I need uniquely identified check boxes or else it only checks and unchecks the first set of boxes. Then once I rename the check box ID the original visibility function doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<input type=checkbox id=0 onClick="change(this,plotname)" checked=true > A
<input type=checkbox id=1 onClick="change(this,plotname)" checked=true > B
<input type=checkbox id=2 onClick="change(this,plotname)" checked=true > C
<input type=checkbox id=3 onClick="change(this,plotname)" checked=true > D

<input id="all_On" type="button" value="All On" onclick="checkTheBoxes([true, true, true, true],<%= chartnumber %>)">
```

JS code:

```
function change(element,name) {
    name.setVisibility(element.id, element.checked);
  }


  function checkTheBoxes(tfarray,section) {
   for (var j = 0;tfarray.length;j++){

        document.getElementById(j).checked = tfarray[j]
        document.getElementById(j).onclick()
        //I have been using the section input to identify plots with the renamed IDs
      }
 }
```

I believe the problem lies in the "this" call when passing through the change function. When I probe with Firebug the element is input#3 if I click check box number 3 and this works. However if I have renamed the ID something like plot2box3 the firebug element is input#plot2box3 which I believe the setVisibilty function doesn't know what to do with.

The question is then, how do I keep the "this" reference outputting the correct element while being able to uniquely call the check box.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use some attribute other than "id" to store the series index, perhaps <input type=checkbox index=0 ...>

Comment: @ user2657998 -- Can you please describe the solution bit detail as I could not be able to implement it.
<input type="checkbox" checked="" onclick="change(this)" index="0">
<label for="0"> load average </label>
function change(el) {
           graph_obj_$report_number.setVisibility(el.getAttribute(index), el.checked);
  }

Comment: @danvk -- Please let me know in detail.

Comment: hi guys, can you please help me with this