# Dygraph multiple plots - turn them on and off

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am considering the implementation of an HTML5 app based on dygraph that shows multiple plots like this app:
http://www.triplespark.net/elec/pdev/cpld/ise-pfsim/ise-screen-sim-result.png

I'd like to know the opinion of somebody who has some experience with multiple plot with dygraph regarding the implementation of it. As visible in the link above, plots should be stuck one on top of the other, plots should be removable (via check-boxes) and resizeable only horizontally (zoom in and out).

I can basically see two ways:

1) As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088455/dygraphs-setvisibility-with-muiltiple-plots-on-page) draw one single large plot like this:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/color-visibility.html

2) draw multiple plots (my favourite option) in different divs and keep them in synch like this:

http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html

Note that:

1) I do not want to redraw all plots when one plot is added or eliminated.

2) plots can be of many many points (>1M points)

A second question I have is about the type of plot. I was wondering if anybody can see how to give me a hint about the implementation of the "foldable" plot of data_bus[0:7]

Any suggestion would be great. I know that the question is generic, I plan to extend this question with a final example that will show the solution to this problem.

Regards
Fabrizio

Comment: You might find http://dygraphs.com/tests/unboxed-spark.html instructive for getting rid of all the axes and other non-data elements of the chart. The rest of what you're asking should be doable with basic CSS & JS.

Comment: well I just finished the second version of it and it looks like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32964564/vcdr_02/index.html I now wonder if I should have used one single canvas and several plots instead of one canvas per plot. Does it make a big difference in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Not the most elegant, but should do the job.

```
‹script›
data= [
      [new Date('2014/09/26 05:33 UTC'),1, 5],
      [new Date('2014/09/26 05:34 UTC'),2, 6],
      [new Date('2014/09/26 05:35 UTC'),3, 7],
      [new Date('2014/09/26 05:36 UTC'),4, 8]];
function plot(){
  var x=[0,0];
  if(document.opt.normal.checked==true)
  {
    x[0]=1;
  }
  if(document.opt.mean.checked==true)
  {
    x[1]=1;
  }
  var temp=[];
  for(var i=0;i‹data.length;i++)
  {
     temp.push([data[i][0]]);
     if(x[0]==1) temp[i].push(data[i][1]);
     if(x[1]==1) temp[i].push(data[i][1]);
  }
  g= new Dygraph(document.getElementById('chartarea'),temp);
}

‹/script›
‹body onload="plot();"›
    ‹div id="chartarea"›‹/div›
    ‹form name="opt" action="#"x›
        ‹input type="checkbox" name="normal" onclick="plot();" checked/›‹span›y1‹/span›
        ‹br›‹input type="checkbox" name="mean" onclick="plot();"/›‹span›y2‹/span›
‹/body›
```

Edit: Just found out: dygraph setVisibility method can be used to avoid re-creating dygraphs for every toggle.